# Flutter, what is the _shared package?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am following an example called flutter_vignettes to construct a nice UI/UX.

However, all of these examples are using _shared packages.

[image]

what is this exactly?  Can't I call it like other dependencies in pusbspec.yaml? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an [unpublished package](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#dependencies-on-unpublished-packages) (kind of inner package). Other `vignettes` are using this unpublished package.

```
dependencies:
  ...
  shared:
    path: ../_shared/
```

You cannot add it to your own app without copping files, because it's not on `pub.dev`, and technically it's not a library. But you just can copy it, it's on MIT license.